# Why is there a cookie in the req.session in node express?

Tags: node.js, session, cookies, express

It's more for my understanding. Why is there a cookie object in the req.session in express?
I use req.session to store the login status and username.
The cookie object in req.session is the same as the cookie properties in the client cookie, placed by express.parseCookie but without sessionID. 
Can anyone explain why this is in there? 
It cant be for the purpose to identify cookie and session because thats already made by the cookie value and the session ID (req.session.ID), or am I'm wrong?

```
- req.session --> 
{ cookie: 
{ path: '/',
 _expires: null,
 originalMaxAge: null,
 httpOnly: true },
  loggedIn: true,
  username: 'luidpold' }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For convenience. It’s the cookie associated with the session, and you can query/modify it.

The session handler in Express comes from Connect. The [documentation for Connect](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/session.html) says:

> ### Session#cookie
>
> Each session has a unique cookie object accompany it. This allows you
>   to alter the session cookie per visitor. For example we can set
>   `req.session.cookie.expires` to false to enable the cookie to remain for
>   only the duration of the user-agent.
>
> ### Session#maxAge
>
> Alternatively `req.session.cookie.maxAge` will return the time remaining
>   in milliseconds, which we may also re-assign a new value to adjust the
>   `.expires` property appropriately.

Comment: What is the diffrence between the cookie we can find in the req.cookies which we can alter using res.cookie('somekey', 'somevalue'); and the cookie in the session : req.session.cookie ?. are the latter's properties a kind of metadata for the former ? So when changing .expires or maxAge values which one of these cookies will be modified ? also i couldn't in any way add any more property to the session cookie using req.session.cookie.myvar. and anyway i don't think that it's the cookie that will be stored in the browser as it doesn't have the connect.sid.

Comment: why I can't add items to that cookie object ?

Comment: @maysara `req.session.cookie` is used for setting the expiry date of the session stored in the memoryStore (or any database you've defined), it is not meant to be used as cookie to store data.